# Vector-list comparison in R

Tags: r, list, vector, comparison

I am currently trying to check if a list(containing multiple vectors filled with values) is equal to a vector. Unfortunately the following functions did not worked for me: `match()`, `any()`, `%in%`. An example of what I am trying to achieve is given below:

Lets say:

```
lists=list(c(1,2,3,4),c(5,6,7,8),c(9,7))
vector=c(1,2,3,4)
answer=match(lists,vector)
```

When I execute this it does return `False` values instead of a positive result. When I compare a vector with a vector is working but when I compare a vector with a list it seems that it can not work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you want the result to be (for example do you care about vector order?) but regardless you'll need to think about `lapply`. For example,

```
##Create some data
R> lists=list(c(1,2,3,4),c(5,6,7,8),c(9,7)) 
R> vector=c(1,2,3,4)
```

then we use `lapply` to go through each list element and **apply** a function. In this case, I've used the `match` function (since you mentioned that in your question):

```
R> lapply(lists, function(i) all(match(i, vector)))
[[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
[1] NA
```

It's probably worth converting to a vector, so

```
R> unlist(lapply(lists, function(i) all(match(i, vector))))
[1] TRUE   NA   NA
```

and to change `NA` to FALSE, something like:

```
m = unlist(lapply(lists, function(i) all(match(i, vector))))
m[is.na(m)] = FALSE
```

Comment: You might want to mention `identical` if you do care about order.  And instead of converting the output of lapply to a vector, it's usually safer to use vapply.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `intersect`, something like this :

```
lapply(lists,intersect,vector)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
numeric(0)

[[3]]
numeric(0)
```